# How to enable production mode in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

Hi I want to know what I need to do in order to enable the production mode in RoR.

When I add the line RailsEnv production to my Apache, after restart it I get an error message "We're sorry, but something went wrong. apache ruby".

The logs are empty, I migrated the db in production mode, compiled the assets, set RAILS_ENV to install all, but I can not run in production, in development works fine.

I use Apache2 + Passenger. Would you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See your `log/production.log` file for exact errors.

Comment: @Uzbekjon The log/production.log contains this:

D, [2016-04-20T13:47:17.810796 #17104] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
D, [2016-04-20T13:47:26.763094 #17140] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
D, [2016-04-20T13:59:40.486879 #4955] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`

Comment: Did you create and migrated your db in production environment (`rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production`)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your production database information correctly defined in **config/database.yml**

You can start Rails in Production mode by launching your application like this:

```
$ rails s -e production -p 80 --bind=0.0.0.0
```

More information about Rails environment settings can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: Thank you @Hugo, I ran the comment but did not work. I configured the database.yml and could migrate correctly.

Appears this error: 
/home/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:114:in `rescue in protection_method_class': Invalid request forgery protection method, use :null_session, :exception, or :reset_session (ArgumentError)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918879/nil-in-request-forgery-protection-when-trying-to-render-a-form-in-rails-3